# This question has no direct relationship to Christianity

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

[According to theistic evolutionists, at what point did humans evolve enough to be considered special to God?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/15091/1100)

This is a philosophical question.

It could be applied to any religion, not just Christianity.

It should be closed.

Comment: "Theistic evolution" is broader than just Christianity. There can be Theistic Evolutionist Muslims, for instance.  But by and large, theistic evolution is a Christian phenomenon, because it is a response against young-earth creation, which is also a Christian phenomenon. But all that aside, the important thing is that the question seeks, by implication of inclusion on this site, the perspective of _Christian theistic evolutionists_, which clearly does have a direct relationship to Christianity.

Answer (score 9):

If you feel it should be closed, vote to close it.  However, "theistic evolution" is undeniably linked to Christianity, specifically.

As evidence of this, a quick [Bing search](https://www.bing.com/search?q=theistic+evolution&pc=MOZI&form=MOZLBR) returns tons of links pointing to various Christian sites - apologetic and otherwise, and in the top results, I see zero results for any other religion.  A [Google search](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=theistic+evolution) returns similar results.

If the community votes to close it, I won't go against it, but your assertion that it has no direct relationship to Christianity clearly doesn't fit the facts.